# Comparing Event Sequences aka Google Analytics Behavior Flow

Tags: algorithm, analytics, apache-spark, web-analytics

I have a series of events stored as JSON in text files. These events represents actions carried out by users on a website - page view, item click, auto-complete etc. What I would like to do is find common journeys through my website - like the "Behavior Flow" tab in google analytics:

[image: Google Analytics Behavior Flow]

I would like to know if there are any standard tools or algorithms or techniques that are useful in producing this functionality. I am currently using Apache Spark, so my preference is for solutions compatible with that.

I can easily build this myself, but my intention is to learn about common best-practices (if any).